# Using flutter plugin in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

**How can i use a Flutter plgin within my existing android project not made with flutter?**

What i have is a **build.gradle** file -

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3")
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

**The flutter plugin i want to use is -**

https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share2

**How can i add it as dependency to my gradle file?**

Comment: You can't, but the relevant Java code is here - you may be able to use it for inspiration. https://github.com/ankushmishra2903-official/whatsapp_share2/blob/main/android/src/main/java/com/example/whatsapp_share/WhatsappShare.java

Comment: @RichardHeap Yes certainly I am inspired. I figured out the Intent codes from the source you provided. I must thank you sir for your help and provided time for the reply. Thank you sir